# Лицензирование windows 2016 server

Tags: windows, лицензирование, windows-2016

Имею бюджетный компьютер с двумя процами каждый с 8 ядрами по 2 потока. Итого 16 потоков на проц. И хоть лицензии вроде я должен покупать на 2 ядра, т.е. всего 8 лицензий, но например esxi воспринимает каждый поток как отдельное ядро, т.е. все таки надо покупать 16 лицензий? Мнения продавцов разделились так что обращаюсь к вам, может есть кто в теме?
P.s. да и я метку windows 2016 создать не могу, создайте плиз